# The monitor screen went dark, even more applications filled

Tags: drivers, dell, bios

Good morning everyone, I need help or an opinion on this situation, I don't have much knowledge about hardware, I hope I can express my current problem.

I started using my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 3583) in my day to day work, this has been a few months ago, on one of these days the screen went dark for a few hours, as if I had turned on the dark mode at maximum. I can see my desktop, but the screen is too dark, the screen shows icons, web pages, whatever I put on it, but the brightness doesn't improve. To save myself, I connected HDMI to my TV, to continue my work and solve this problem later.

I am currently connected with my laptop to my TV. I don't know the exact reason for this, I didn't drop the notebook and it didn't suffer any impact, I've had it for a little over a year and the warranty is over.

I researched further to find out, it might be a video drive, before I used Pop_os, it was Windows 10 when I bought it. I've been using Pop_os for a long time, because it's an Ubuntu distro, I'm passing my problem here, because Dell only supports Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I even installed an older version of Pop, Ubuntu but it didn't work. But I wasn't successful, I followed a step by step to install the Bios because it was out of date, I ended up using the pen drive to carry out the process, I did everything as recommended, platform support, no improvement, the laptop works perfectly. Just that screen issue. It's hard to believe that the screen burned, with such a new product, I bought Dell because it is the most recommended in terms of hardware quality, but I ended up being sad about this issue. I will leave the dell platform support page.

**The only update it has** is the BIOS, with two versions of "exe" and "rcv" installations.

[Dell suporte](https://www.dell.com/support/home/pt-br/product-support/servicetag/0-bFB0ajgvYUhjbEVWY1pTQXFYbS9SZz090/drivers)

[BIOS dos sistemas Dell Inspiron](https://www.dell.com/support/home/pt-br/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=jt2t3&oscode=ubt18&productcode=inspiron-15-3583-laptop)

[image: The Drivers of my laptop]

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're asking here. The backlight has failed on your laptop panel? Also, if you're using Pop, and not Ubuntu then this site cannot provide support. What happens with a live Ubuntu USB? Does the backlight work?

Comment: @popey I asked around here, because the linux version that is available on the Dell website, and UBuntu 18.04 LTS. Imagine you take your smartphone, set it to the lowest brightness level, and go out in the sun. Your screen will be working, but it won't see the apps, it would be the same with the screen on the laptop. This I tried several ways to resolve. I even saw an example of an outdated drive, I entered this site to see if I could update. Because before being Windows, these updates were automatic, as I switched to Linux, I imagine. But their support version is very old